# Limiting QML TextField length causes multibyte-characters to be trimmed off

Tags: qt, unicode, qml, qstring, qlineedit

I have a QML `TextField` and want to limit the length to 16 characters.

```
TextField {
    id: myTextField
    maximumLength: 16
}
```

Say I enter a multibyte-character like "" at the end of a 15 character long string, the emoji gets trimmed and results as �, which is one byte (0x3f in this case). I'm not sure where the 0x3f comes from, because internally the `QString` works with UTF-16, so this might be the result of some back and forth conversion between UTF-8 and UTF-16.

The only way I see right now to avoid this trimming of multibyte-characters is to implement my own `QValidator` where I then need to check the length of my string with a Unicode aware library like ICU.

My Question now: Is there any other easier way to avoid the trimming, that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look at the  emoji:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Column {
        Text { text: "" }               //  
        Text { text: "\u{1f60a}" }        // 
        Text { text: "\u{d83d}\u{de0a}" } // 
        Text { text: "\u{d83d}" }         // �
        Text { text: "\u{de0a}" }         // �
        Text { text: "�" }               // �
        Text { text: "\u{fffd}" }         // �
    }
}
```

It is a codepoint character \u{1f60a} which is made up of \u{d83d} and \u{de0a}. Because you set maximumLength to 16 when you paste the emoji you are only getting one of the characters, i.e. \u{d83d} which Qt recognizes as not a character so it replaces it with \u{fffd} which is a placeholder character for "I don't know".

If you want to limit your input to 16 "characters" but want to eliminate that "I don't know" character you can use RegularExpressionValidator.

```
        maximumLength: 16
        validator: RegularExpressionValidator {
            regularExpression: /[^�]{0,16}/u
        }
```

Alternatively, if you want to limit yourself to 16 codepoint characters, you can do the following:

```
        validator: RegularExpressionValidator {
            regularExpression: /.{0,16}/u
        }
```

Here's a fully working example of the former:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    TextField {
        id: myTextField
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width / 2
        text: ""
        maximumLength: 16
        validator: RegularExpressionValidator {
            regularExpression: /[^�]{0,16}/u
        }
    }
    Text {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        y: parent.height * 3 / 4
        text: myTextField.length
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAB33icfZDPSsNAEMbveYqhR5GkVelhr6UFwYMV8SIKS7Ikg/snTCaaWvICPoE3n0R8JH0EN6HZxhwc2GVnvm+GnR+a0hHDlrc1pk8R/knjlbNMTlfRtcwV7CPwcasa3qDS2SHvAjMBZheUUJc2LRxVcaosK7q0AkpJ/h0ML5hxMVTjPoMEzoLOfqSA2c/H+9t/ZxYajGzQ1OZK2bwbvFgG5VlqzCQ7EnCj8lpLWjclqapCZ+8GbbRTFzQ1CkjuH7+/Ph/289PFsk3qYG+j492BGE0aKPgLXz1RqVc9j7D3VAidu6NFYV4wnMC553Mx4TNCH+t+88Nn2l/Q55zi)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.  One thing I noticed is that this solutions still allows to insert e.g. a composed emoji like '‍' when I already entered 14 characters, which will then show '' which is one part of the composed emoji. If I remove the maximumLength property and only keep the validator /[^�]{0,16}/u, this doesn't happen anymore, but instead I can insert up to 16 times '', which are then counted as single character. @Stephen Quan

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution seems to be implementing a `QValidator`

```
QValidator::State MyValidator::validate(QString & input, int & pos) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(pos)
    if(input.length() <= 16)
        return Acceptable;
    return Invalid;
}
```

No ICU or other libraries needed.